# How does the TLS Client Hello message choose the TLS version?

Tags: tls

Im looking at a Client Hello message in wireshark, the client supports 1.2 and 1.3, but Wireshark says the client used TLSv1.3 record layer when the server hasn't replied yet the choosen version.
[image: Wireshark snapshot]
How can this be explaned?

Also, why after that i see version 1.0 and version 1.2 if version 1.3 was used?

Comment: There are lots of question explain this on information security, https://security.stackexchange.com/q/20803/86735 and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/168390/how-is-the-tls-version-selected-between-client-and-server/168397#168397

Comment: @kelalaka: both those are prior to TLS1.3, which changes the handling of protocol version substantially

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes, however, this https://security.stackexchange.com/a/201699/86735

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is better asked at [security.se] but it already has been asked over there.

Answer (score 2):

TLS 1.3 record layer is shown because the ClientHello contains TLS 1.3 as supported version. This can be seen at the bottom of the following image. See also [TLS record layer and Handshake protocol](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/18169/tls-record-layer-and-handshake-protocol/) at ask.wireshark.org.

[image]

Comment: And this mostly-nonuse of the record layer version, and even the fixed/legacy version in ClientHello and ServerHello, replaced by the new supported_versions extension, is detailed in RFC8446 5.1-2, 4.1.2-3, 4.2.1, and Appendix D.